# Building array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to build an array in javascript from user input on my HTML form. It seems the array is building fine until it gets to the `.push`, I then get an error

> employeeid undefined

, even though I know it's being populated and I can see this when I run debug mode.

**HTML**

```
  <div class="wel" align="left">

    <form class="form-signin">

        <p>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="EmployeeID" name="EmployeeID" placeholder="EmployeeID" required="" autofocus="" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fullname" name="fullname" placeholder="FullName" required="" autofocus="" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="UserName" required="" autofocus="" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="Email" name="Email" placeholder="Email" required="" autofocus="" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="Password" name="Password" placeholder="password" required="" autofocus="" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="Password1" name="ConfirmPassword" placeholder="password" required="" autofocus="" />
        </p>

        <a id='subButton' class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="vertical-align: bottom">submit</a>

    </form>
</div
```

**javascript**

```
  $(document)
    .ready(function() {

        var arrayDetails = new Array();
        var holdingArray = new Array();

        function newEntry(employeeId, fullname, username, email, password) {

            this.employeeId = employeeId;
            this.fullname = fullname;
            this.username = username;
            this.email = email;
            this.Password = password;

        }

            $("#subButton")
            .click(function () {

                debugger;

                var success = true;

                var password = document.getElementById("Password");
                var password1 = document.getElementById("Password1");

                if (password.value !== password1.value)
                {
                    alert("Password do not match");
                }
                else
                {
                    var employeeIdEntered = document.getElementById("EmployeeID").value;

                    if (employeeIdEntered === "") {
                        success = false;
                    }

                    var fullnameentered = document.getElementById("fullname").value;

                    if (fullnameentered === "") {
                        success = false;
                    }

                    var usernameEntered = document.getElementById("username").value;

                    if (usernameEntered === "") {
                        success = false;
                    }

                    var emailEntered = document.getElementById("Email").value;

                    if (emailEntered === "") {
                        success = false;
                    }

                    var passwordEnterned = document.getElementById("Password").value;

                    if (passwordEnterned === "") {
                        success = false;
                    }

                    var entry = newEntry(employeeIdEntered,
                        fullnameentered,
                        usernameEntered,
                        emailEntered,
                        passwordEnterned);

                    arrayDetails.push(entry);
                };

                if (success)
                {
                    sendToController();
                } else
                {
                    alert("");
                }

            });
```

Comment: Your code doesn't mention a variable called `employeeid` at all

Comment: What does the error message contain exactly?

Comment: and what is your `newEntry()` function

Comment: I have edited the code section.

Comment: Your `newEntry()` function is missing a `return` statement. Don't add the attributes to `this`, do instead a `var res = {}; res.employeeId=employeeId; ... return res;`

Comment: Or just add `new` in front of the constructor call in the case they were actually wanting to make a new instance, which will return the new instance automatically

Comment: I can't believe that the `employeeid undefined` error occurs in `arrayDetails.push()` or `newEntry()` because I cannot see an access to a possible undefined `employeeId` variable. Is it likely that the error occurs in `sendToController()`?

Answer (score 1):

Your `newEntry()` function is missing a `return` statement. Don't add the attributes to this, do instead a

```
function newEntry(employeeId, fullname, username, email, password) {
        var res = {};
        res.employeeId = employeeId;
        res.fullname = fullname;
        res.username = username;
        res.email = email;
        res.Password = password;
        return res;
    }
```